# when using pyserial connection to /dev/ttyS0 second time throws error termios.error: (22, 'Invalid argument')

Tags: python, pyserial

Below is my sample Python script. I am using `socat` to simulate `/dev/ttyS0` serial connection. When I run my Python script first time I do not get any errors. But when the Python script stops executing and I run it for second time I get the below error. I have set `parity=serial.PARITY_NONE`. Also if I stop and start my socat script, then I am able to run my Python script one more time. Eventhough, I am calling `ser.close()` at the end, I am assume there is a specific way to stop a connection to serial port so that it can be reconnected. I am new to this serial port programming any help would be great.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/home/tk/tkworkspace/billing-system-main/test/WeightMachineReading2.py",
line 13, in <module>
     ser = serial.Serial(   File "/home/tk/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/serial/serialutil.py",
line 244, in __init__
     self.open()   File "/home/tk/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/serial/serialposix.py",
line 332, in open
    self._reconfigure_port(force_update=True)   File "/home/tk/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/serial/serialposix.py",
 line 517, in _reconfigure_port
    termios.tcsetattr( termios.error: (22, 'Invalid argument')
```

Socat script:

```
socat -d -d pty,link=/dev/ttyS0,raw,group-late=dialout,mode=660,echo=0 pty,link=/dev/ttyS1,raw,group-late=dialout,mode=660,echo=0
```

Python Script:

```
import time
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyS0',
    baudrate=115200,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS,
)

out = ''
for i in range(1):
    waitingQueue = ser.inWaiting()
    time.sleep(2)
    if waitingQueue == 0:
        weight = "-- kg"
    print(weight.strip())

ser.close()
```